# Javascript replace with /gi and array-iterator

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, replace, flags

how can i make this work:

```
        var storedValues = $('<table class="table_groessentabelle_custom"></table>');

        // contains excel paste content from Libreoffice
        $('textarea[name=excel_data]').bind("paste", function(e){
            var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
            storedValues.append(pastedData);
        });

        //localisation - tables (just a subset)
        var de = ["Größe","Höhe","Weite","Damen","Herren","Kinder",];
        var fr = ["Pointure","Hauteur","Largeur","Femme","Homme","Enfants"];

        var de_storedvalues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( storedValues.html() )); 
        var fr_storedvalues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( storedValues.html() )); 

        for (var i = 0; i < de.length; i++) {
            // doesnt work, no fields are translated 
            fr_storedvalues = fr_storedvalues.replace(/de[i]/gi,fr[i]);
        }
```

it works without the /gi flag but only transates the first entry of a given variable. if there is more than one entry, the rest stays in german.

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var find = de[i];
var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
fr_storedvalues = fr_storedvalues.replace(regex,fr[i]);
```